# How to configure S/MIME on my iPhone 12

Tags: iphone, ios, email, smime

I'm trying to enable my S/MIME certificate but I can't. When I go to the Email Tab in settings, click accounts, click iCloud, then I go to the Account section in settings (Not the one in the iCloud section). I'm looking for the account section there but I can't find it.

Please help!

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the S/MIME certificate with its private key included. I assume you already have done that. Otherwise, please post a separate question.

After that, go to *Settings > Email > Accounts*. From there, select your account, then scroll down to tap on *Advanced Settings*. Then again scroll down to *Sign* and *Encrypt by Default*.

If your S/MIME certificate has been installed properly, and the email address in the certificate matches the email address configured for the mail account, then you should be able to tap on *Sign* and *Encrypt by Default* and select the certificate for each purpose.

After that, iOS Mail should be set up to sign and receive encrypted email. Note that you need the recipients' public certificates before you can start sending encrypted email to them.

See also [Use S/MIME to send encrypted messages in an Exchange environment in iOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202345) which, despite its title, also describes how to set it up for other types of mail accounts.